# Getting data frames back to the global enviroment in R

Tags: r

Managed to clear my workspace in RStudio and didnt know my data frames would be removed from the Global Enviroment. Now I cant do anything with them without getting `error object 'dataframe' not found`.

How do I re-attach them to the global envirment?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cleared the workspace then they're gone.  So... do whatever you did to create them in the first place if you want to get them back.

Comment: Even though I have them in the top bar and can loook at them? 

Wow, R are brutal :(

Comment: You should use this as a learning experience about how to make a reproducible script. This would allow you to clear your environment whenever and still be able to retrieve your data.

Comment: Yes, a valuable experience for sure So I would have to script it if I want to use it again? No way to just save the data frames?

Comment: If the `data.frames` were still in memory you could save them (`write.table`, `saveRDS`, ...). Once you deleted them, there is no way to save them. As @MichaelBird said, if you write the code to create the `data.frame` in a script rather than typing it live into the console, you can always recreate the `data.frame`.

Comment: @SuchARush Is it really brutal that it did exactly what you asked it to?

Comment: For you who know r in and out maybe not. For me who just wanted to clear out things I didnt use and not delete anything: definitely.

In everyday talk, clearing a workspace doesnt mean delete anything ;)

Comment: @SuchARush I guess I'm wondering what you thought clearing the workspace would do?

Comment: @Dason Clear out the consolle and values Id set. Not delete my data frames. Its not easy to know when you dont know how the workspace are defined in R. Now I know. Clearing workspace is destroying everything you have on file

Comment: But data.frames are values that you've set.  Oh well. Take this as a learning experience.  If you didn't keep your code in scripts before now you might seriously consider it (as you should!)

Comment: Yes but  since you import it from other files you could think it gets saved in some sort of source file/data file. What seems obv to you may not to someone new in this field. 

Really appreciate your help anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have them in the top bar and can look at them, and there are not too big u can copy paste it in an excel file.

Comment: Brilliant, but its too big unfortunately :(

Comment: haha then you'll have to create them again :) good luck my friend =)